# exec command being weird(python)

Tags: python

The exec() function is not executing a string correctly.

```
def servlistappend(x):
    file = open("blarg.txt",'r')
    read = str(file.read())
    print(read)
    tbe = "list = "+read
    print(tbe)
    exec(tbe)
    print(list)
    list.append(x)
    print(list)
    file.close()
    file = open("blarg.txt",'w')
    file.write(str(list))
    file.close()
def servlistremove(x):
    file = open("blarg.txt",'r')
    read = str(file.read())
    print(read)
    tbe = "list = "+read
    print(tbe)
    exec(tbe)
    print(list)
    if x in list:
        list.remove(x)
    else:
        print("that element does not exist")
    print(list)
    file.close()
    file = open("blarg.txt",'w')
    file.write(str(list))
    file.close()
servlistremove(2345)
```

The contents of blarg.txt are:
[1234,2345,2345,2345]

When run, print(read) correctly outputs the string `[1234,2345,2345,2345]` and print(tbe) correctly outputs the string`list = [1234, 2345, 2345, 2345]`. After that, exec(tbe) and print(list) outputs  `<class 'list'>` while it is instead supposed to output the list `[1234,2345,2345,2345]`. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign a variable to the `exec` call. So `list = exec(tbe)`

Also, it is generally a bad practice to use `exec` or `eval`. I'd recommend that you use either `json.load` or `ast.literal_eval` if you want to convert a string to a python object.

The reason for the `<class 'list'>` printout is that `list` is a python builtin and you just printed out what that builtin object is.

Edit:
I forgot `exec` wouldn't return the list, you have to use `eval`